# NoClassDefFoundError in Activity Test using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to get activity testing going using espresso but I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError (see stack out put below). I've tried a few things that I saw on stackoverflow but none worked for me

```
10-04 23:18:28.901  13845-13845/com.example.test E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.example.test.ui.SplashActivity', referenced from method com.example.test.test.ui.SplashActivityTest.<init>
10-04 23:18:28.901  13845-13845/com.example.test W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve const-class 2480 (Lcom/example/test/ui/SplashActivity;) in Lcom/example/test/test/ui/SplashActivityTest;
10-04 23:18:28.901  13845-13845/com.example.test D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0000
10-04 23:18:28.901  13845-13858/com.example.test I/TestRunner﹕ started: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
10-04 23:18:28.911  13845-13845/com.example.test I/GoogleInstr﹕ Activities that are still in CREATED to PAUSED: 0
10-04 23:18:28.911  13845-13858/com.example.test I/TestRunner﹕ failed: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
10-04 23:18:28.911  13845-13858/com.example.test I/TestRunner﹕ ----- begin exception -----
10-04 23:18:28.911  13845-13858/com.example.test I/TestRunner﹕ junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testNextActivityWasLaunchedWithIntent (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.test.ui.SplashActivity
            at com.example.test.test.ui.SplashActivityTest.<init>(SplashActivityTest.java:21)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
            at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:118)
            at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:149)
            at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:57)
            at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:80)
            at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:443)
            at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:424)
            at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:370)
            at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:114)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4319)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    )
            at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:97)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
            at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
            at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
            at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
            at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
            at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
            at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
            at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
            at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

My build script:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:1.6.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "com.example.test"

        testApplicationId "com.example.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        testHandleProfiling true
        testFunctionalTest true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
    }


}

apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        '../app/src/main/java'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: '../app/build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testDebug.exec')

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'


    androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-integration'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
        exclude group:'com.android.support'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-integration'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `testApplicationId "com.example.test"` is that intentional, shouldn't there be a "test" suffix:

`totestApplicationId "com.example.test.test"`

Comment: That was it exactly. I had the testApplicationId set to the same value as applicationId